# Faking WPF Manipulation Events

Tags: wpf, multi-touch

I want to fake manipulation (or touch) events using a mouse / keyboard. When I try to raise the events using:

```
RoutedEventArgs e = new RoutedEventArgs(ManipulationStartedEvent,this);
RaiseEvent(e);
```

Gives me the error "Cannot convert `RoutedEventArgs` to `ManipulationStartedEventArgs`, and attempting to create a new `ManipulationStartedEventArgs` results in an error as there are no constructors for `ManipulationStartedEventArgs`.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is to create a Custom Touch Device by extending the Touch Device class with appropriate mouse inputs.

[An example using Microsoft Multipoint SDK (Multi-Mouse)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2010/01/30/custom-touch-devices.aspx).